# Fetching data dynamically in table

Tags: ajax, jsp, servlets

I am having a table **STUDENT** say having three columns :

```
RollNo  Name  Age of students
```

Now i want to search for students in my web application in such a way that as i press'A' students whose name starts with 'A' all comes down in a tabular form below in my page and if i press next button say 'B' then only students matching the criteria remains on the page and all other are gone.

Main Problem is How to show these results in form a dynamic sort of tabular form.Please help.
I am working in jsp and new learner to ajax.

Comment: what you have tried, add to your question?

Answer (score 0):

I will give you a solution without ajax.

First of all retrive all your data from your database table to your html table
Incase you dont just refer this link http://www.roseindia.net/answers/viewqa/JSP-Interview-Questions/27750-how-to-display-values-from-database-into-table-using-jsp.html
(not the best link though but will help you incase you dont know).

Once retireved you will get all the database table data in your html table and then you can implement the search using **dataTables** this is using jquery.This is the link to download it
https://code.google.com/p/jquery-datatables-column-filter/downloads/detail?name=JQuery-DataTables-ColumnFilter.zip&can=1&q=

and as an example you can check this run the index.html after downloading it.